# Zabbix add host

Tags: zabbix

The color of ZBX Availability is only red and getting following error message: Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[IP]:10050]: [4] Interrupted system call. I added a new host based on documentation zabbix
And ideas how to resolve this issues?

Comment: This is too vague. Basically, Zabbix server cannot connect to the agent on that port to the address you specified. This is also not a programming question.

Comment: You need to make sure the local zabbix-agent that's installed on that client is operating correctly and listening on port 10050. Also make sure the local firewall isn't blocking the ability for the Zabbix server to connect to this client.